# Postgresql get all account ids of users, where users have account ids 33, 34 and 35

Tags: postgresql

Note: accounts are shared by users

The query is to get all account ids of users, where users have account ids 33, 34 and 35 for example.

```
SELECT A.id FROM accounts A
INNER JOIN account_user AU ON AU.account_id = A.id
WHERE AU.user_id IN (
    SELECT AU.user_id FROM account_user AU
    WHERE AU.account_id IN (33, 34, 35)
    GROUP BY AU.user_id
)
GROUP BY A.id;
```

Any other way to write this?

What I Am Doing
Finding all the unique users_ids that have account_ids 33, 34 and 35
Finding all the unique account_ids that each user has. (accounts are shared between users)
Returning all the unique account_ids

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing - what problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: I'm just seeing if there is a better way / more efficient way of writing this.

Comment: I guess I'll use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join if all the data you need is in 1 table:
    SELECT user_id, account_id
     FROM accounts
     WHERE account_id IN (33,34,35)
    ;

IF you need a distinct list just use distinct:
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id
     FROM accounts
     WHERE account_id IN (33,34,35)
    ;

HTH,
Cindy